# How to save to database Client IP Address of Visitors Machine in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, ip-address

am trying to get IP Address of client Machine `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];` it's working fine.

Get IP On page load

```
public ActionResult AddCompany()
        {
            get_IP();
            return View();
        }
```

get_IP code

```
public void get_IP()
        {
            string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }
            ViewBag.IPAddress = ipAddress;
        }
```

But when user register the form get IP address value also save in the data base..

Cs.html File

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <h1 class="page-header">Add Company</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IPAddress)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShortName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShortName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShortName)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)*@
                    @Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "---Select Country----")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <b>State: </b>
                <select id="state"></select><br />
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>City: </b>
                <select id="city"></select><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>
```

I create one `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IPAddress)` hidden filed value but it's not working ..

On page load IPAddress Value is showing .after i click to save button the `Ip` value is not saved to the database..

AddCompany

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCompany(Company cmp)
        {
            using (DataContext entities = new DataContext())
            {
                entities.Company.Add(cmp);
                entities.SaveChanges();
                int id = cmp.CompanyID;
                Session.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("Index");
            }
            return View(cmp);

        }
```

Any idea How to save  client IP Adrress from the database..

Class File

```
[Table("MySecondMVCDemo")]
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Company Name")]
        [Display(Name = "CompanyName")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Short Name")]
        [Display(Name = "ShortName")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Email Address")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Email Address")]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Mobile No")]
        [Display(Name = "MobileNo")]
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public Int32? IPAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about *HiddenFor* because I have not use it before.
How I hid fields before was like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IPAddress, new { @class = "sr-only", @type = "hidden" })
```

You can add the bootstrap class **sr-only** to make sure it is hidden.
Make sure you check your browser inspector to see whether the hidden field has a value.

If posted and is still not saving, then try to assign the IpAddress identity to the form field value before saving it like this:

```
cmp.IPAddress = Request.Form["IPAddress"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store IP address as a string instead of Int32

Please use code from here to get IP Address

http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.in/2010/09/aspnet-get-ipv4-address-even-if-user-is.html